# how can i define mysql's empty return?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable like that;

```
$x=mysql_query("SELECT uye,yorum,tarih FROM bahisyorum WHERE bahisid='$bahisid'");
```

I want to show a error message if this mysql query return with zero result. But if it returns with results i want to show them.

How can i do that? I tried isset and empty but it did not worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  the **[mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)** command:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($x)==0) {
    //Show Error Message
}
else {
    //Perform actions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

quoting from the [reference page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a SELECT statement